# An interesting limit of certain $q$-binomial sums.

Tags: limits

Let $\binom{n}{j}_q$ be a $q$-binomial coefficient. I would like to find 
a simple method to prove that

$$
\lim_{q\to1}\frac{\sum\limits_{j =  0}^{2n} (-1)^j q^{m(j^2+j)}
\binom{2n}{j}_q}{\sum\limits_{j =  0}^{2n} (-1)^j q^{(j^2+j)} \binom{2n}{j}_q}
= (2m-1)^n.
$$

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: You don't need to write $q{-}{>}1$; you can write $q\to1$. That is standard.  (I changed it.) ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you limit is not exactly correct.  I find for $n=1,..,6$ that the limit gives ${m,2 m-1,m (2 m-1),(2 m-1)^2,m (2 m-1)^2,(2 m-1)^3}$ so for even $n$, the limit is $(2m-1)^{\frac{m}{2}}$ and for odd $n$ the limit is $m(2m-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$.  I have only checked with with a compute algebra system up to $n=10$, I have not worked on a proof yet.
I believe I can prove as and induction step, that if the limit formula is correct for even $n$, that is $lim=(2m-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}$ then for $n+1, lim=m(2m-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}$

Comment: you are right, I had a typo. I have corrected it.